I am receiving this error when installing Samba-common-bin
"Error while installing package: installed samba-common-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1"

"error exit status 1" is a generic error that simply means that some subprocess failed. That is not enough information to offer useful advice. Edit your question to show us the complete terminal output of sudo apt update and of sudo apt upgrade and of sudo apt install samba-common-bin. Complete means complete -- provide all three, and please do not edit or summarize.

Please also give the version of Ubuntu you are using.
